# Not receiving any email notifications from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext, email-notifications

I am using Jenkins 1.520 In Ubuntu and Email-ext plugin 2.32. I didn't see like editable email notification options in configure system. Is it possible to add editable email notifications. i can able to send test emails. or is it possible by down grading the email plugins. do let me know how to downgrade the email-ext plugin

Answer (score 0):

As to down grading the email plugins,enter Manage Jenkins ->Manage Plugins ->Installed.
You will see the downgrade option of each plugin.If there's no downgrade option here, try to uninstall the plugin.

However I don't think you need to downgrade the plugin here.Enter Manage Jenkins ->Extended E-mail Notification ,**Default Content** is what you need to edit.

If you want to edit different content for each jobs , enter  -> Configure -> Post-build Actions -> Add Editable Email Notification. **Default Content** is what you need to edit.

Comment: i don't see downgrade for this plugin and i do see for only some plugin